# Android Studio couldn't see Androidmanifest.xml after adding Google Maps

Tags: android

My iOS app is working very well but after I edited Android Manifest and added Google Maps information, my Android app at first was working but it couldn't connect with Google Maps. I edited it again and after that I changed with previous saved one that I had but now I send you the final error that Android Studio shows me, please help to fix this problem.

The error is this:

> zipro W 09-13 09:36:37  8721 108688 Error opening archive
> /Users/johnhabibpour/StudioProjects/08-19-2021
> AM/absolutestonedesignpro/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
> Invalid file ERROR: dump failed because resource AndroidManifest.xml
> not found Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The
> command failed   Command:
> /Users/johnhabibpour/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/aapt dump
> xmltree /Users/johnhabibpour/StudioProjects/08-19-2021
> AM/absolutestonedesignpro/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
> AndroidManifest.xml. No application found for
> TargetPlatform.android_x86. Is your project missing an
> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml? Consider running "flutter
> create ." to create one.

Comment: delete that app.apk and try running again

Comment: I tried to edit the question to improve it, but if I have changed the meaning anywhere then please edit to correct it.